# What does "delete all disabled modules" do in Jenkins?

Tags: maven, jenkins

In Jenkins, I have the option to "delete all disabled modules" on main page of some projects. What does that do?

Edit: What is a "disabled module"? Jenkins doesn't have modules, it has projects and plugins. Maven has modules but what there is no way to "disable" a module in Maven. You can only comment it out or delete the element in the POM.

Comment: Can't get more "English" than that. I believe the feature speaks for itself.

Comment: What is a "disabled module"? Jenkins doesn't have modules, it has projects and plugins. Maven has modules but what there is no way to "disable" a module in Maven. You can only comment it out or delete the element in the POM.

Comment: Where do you have this option?

Comment: [This](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remove+all+disabled+modules+in+Maven+jobs) seems to disagree. When you select the Maven job, then select the sub-project/module, can you disable it, like a regular job?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When changing the module structure of your Maven project, Jenkins has no way to know why a module suddenly appeared or vanished.

Did you add a new module? Jenkins will expect it to stay.

A module disappeared? Maybe you moved it to a profile or maybe you deleted the module or maybe you renamed it or maybe the build failed early - Jenkins can't tell for sure.

So it keeps the old module around. Say you build a project and it has the modules `parent`, 'a' and `b`. After a while, you rename `b` to `x`. When you display this build in Jenkins, you'll see four Maven modules:

```
parent      0.01s
a           0.3s
b (skipped)
x           0.5s
```

Jenkins keeps `b` around since it can't be sure when to delete it.

If you see such "skipped" entries and you're sure that they don't belong there, click on `Delete All Disabled Modules` to get rid of the obsolete ones *after* making sure that the build still contains all the modules it should.